# Automatically creating an organic group for each new user

Tags: 7, rules, organic-groups

I would like to automatically create an organic group for each newly registered user. I checked all its settings, no such option with organic groups module, then I checked the rules module but no luck there too.

Comment: why would anyone give this post negative reputation.

Answer (score 0):

The [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module will allow you create new OG node after saving a new user account. Just do the following:

- Create your rule and add an "After saving new user account" event to it
- In the action section, select create a new entity
- In the value section, select node
- In the Content type, select the "your group"
- Fill the title as you need; you can do this using the token
- Fill the author

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so here is another way to do it, if you dont want to do it with rules;

```
    <?php
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 *
 * Alters the user registration form by adding a custom submit handler.
 */
function custom_user_insert(&$edit, $account, $category) {
  if (isset($account->is_new) && !empty($account->is_new)) {
        //print '<pre>';print_r($account);die;
        $groupnode = new stdClass();
        $groupnode->type = 'group'; // Group node type
        $groupnode->status = 1;
        //$groupnode->language ='de';
        $groupnode->uid =  $account->uid;
        $groupnode->title = 'group name comes here';    
        //here I save the uid from the activated user
                $groupnode->field_group_user['und'][0]['value'] = $account->uid;
        //$groupnode->{OG_GROUP_FIELD}['und'][0]['value'] = '1';

        node_save($groupnode);  
        $nid = $groupnode->nid;
        og_group('node',$nid, array(
        //"entity type"       => 'user', // defaults to user
        "entity"        => $account->uid,
        'field_name' => 'og_user_node',
        'state' => 1,//OG_STATE_ACTIVE
        'force_reload' => TRUE
        ));
        //drupal_set_message('Do it!');
        // Changes the users role in the group (1 = non-member, 2 = member, 3 = administrator member)
        og_role_grant('node',$nid, $account->uid, 12);

        $assign_grp_userid=loadusers_by_role('coaching expert');

         og_group('node',$nid, array(
        //"entity type"       => 'user', // defaults to user
        "entity"        => $assign_grp_userid,
        'field_name' => 'og_user_node',
        'state' => 1,//OG_STATE_ACTIVE
        'force_reload' => TRUE
        ));
        //drupal_set_message('Do it!');
        // Changes the users role in the group (1 = non-member, 2 = member, 3 = administrator member)
        og_role_grant('node',$nid, $account->uid, 11); 
  }
}
```